# Firebase get users rank by getting his score in android

Tags: android, database, firebase

I would like to fetch the users rank from by using the score that has been used in the database. I have the database as:

scores-> uid -> score

[image: data image]

Here in the image I would like to sort the data of score in descending order,assign ranks to them (1 being the highest scorer's rank, 2 being the second and so on) and retrieve the current user's rank.

I have found solutions which help in sorting the users but how do I set their rank and find the rank of the current user is the problem.

```
    private void getHighestScore() {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
    Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("score").limitToLast(1);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            userlist = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User score = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                Log.d("test", " values is " + score.getName() + " " + score.getScore());

                       userlist.add(score.getScore()+user.getName());


            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

The above code has been used to add data to a list in a sorted manner. The problem being how to set the rank of the current user in the application

[firebase retrieve highest 100 score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489398/firebase-retrieve-highest-100-score)

[query for getting top 10 highest scores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076545/query-for-getting-top-10-highest-scores)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results *in the question*.

Comment: @GordonLinoff have made changes please check

Comment: Please show some code you've tried. For example, what's stopping you from querying for the scores, get a list of users, then order that by score?

Comment: Try making userlist an array list of User objects that you can sort, not strings